# Only show \NAME in \listoftheorems

Tags: table-of-contents, theorems, amsthm, thmtools

I am using the `thmtools` package, and I want to modify `\listoftheorems` to only print the name of the theorem. For example, my document might look something like the one shown below. When I compile this document, the first line of my "List of Problems" is "1 Problem (Name 1) ... 1". However, I want it to be "1 Name 1 ... 1". Is there anyway to do this? I figured out how to renew the command `\listtheoremname` in order to change the title of list of problems. The documentation for `thmtools` says "If you're daring, the code for theorem type "lemma" is in `\l@lemma` and so on." This makes me optimistic that I can renew the `\l@problem` command to do what I want, but I don't know enough about TeX to make this happen.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheorem{problem}
\renewcommand{\listtheoremname}{List of Problems}

\begin{document}

\listoftheorems

\begin{problem}[Name 1]
description of problem 1
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}[Name 2]
description of problem 2
\end{problem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180747/editing-format-of-list-of-theorems-in-thmtools

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
\makeatletter
%\show\ll@problem gives default definition:
% \protect \numberline {\csname the\thmt@envname \endcsname }\thmt@thmname \ifx
% \@empty \thmt@shortoptarg \else \protect \thmtformatoptarg {\thmt@shortoptarg 
% }\fi
\def\ll@problem{%
  \protect\numberline{\theproblem}\thmt@shortoptarg%
}
\makeatother
```

it will leave no text if there's no title, but that sounds OK for your case.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16498/4427