# \listoftheorems: named theorems and optional arguments

Tags: thmtools

In the following, I have three kinds of theorems:

1. an "ordinary" theorem, which just has the head "Theorem", as in the 3rd;
2. a theorem having both a head and a note, "Theorem (...)", as in the 2nd; and
3. a `namedtheorem`, where the note becomes the name, as in the 1st.

***Desired format:***
[image: Wanted form for list of theorems]

**Question:** What modification is needed so that the output from `\listoftheorems` removes the parentheses from the `namedtheorem` entry but preseres the parentheses of the note in a theorem having both head and note?

**Failed attempt 1:** removes parentheses for `namedtheorem` but unfortunately also removes them from the entry with the note.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,thmtools}

% For \listoftheorems
\renewcommand\thmtformatoptarg[1]{#1} % remove parens
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\thmt@mklistcmd}{\thmt@thmname}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\swapnumbers

\declaretheoremstyle[
  headformat=\NAME\NUMBER\let\thmt@space\@empty\NOTE,
  bodyfont=\slshape,
]{thmstyle}
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem,style=thmstyle]{theorem}
    
\declaretheoremstyle[
  postheadspace=0.5em,
  notebraces={}{},
  headformat=\NUMBER\let\thmt@space\@empty\NOTE,
  notefont=\bfseries,
  bodyfont=\slshape,
]{namedthmstyle}
\declaretheorem[
  style=namedthmstyle,
  name=Theorem,
  title = {},
  numberlike=theorem
]{namedtheorem}

\begin{document}

\listoftheorems[ignoreall,onlynamed={theorem,namedtheorem}]

\bigskip

\begin{namedtheorem}[Heine-Borel Theorem]
A closed and bounded subset of Euclidean $n$-space is compact.
\end{namedtheorem}

\begin{theorem}[compact subset of Hausdorff space]
A compact subset of a Hausdorff space is closed in that space.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
The square on the hypotenuse of a right triangle equals the sum of the squares on the other two sides.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image: No parens whatsoever in listoftheorems]
**Failed attempt 2:** Comment out the line `\renewcommand\thmtformatoptarg[1]{#1}`. Then parentheses still remain around the entry for the `namedtheorem`.

[image: Unwanted parens around name of named theorem]

**Question, restated:** Thus, how can I somehow combine different treatments of a `theorem` having a parenthesized note, on the one hand, and a `namedtheorem`, on the other hand?

*Related:* https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193020/13492, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/180749/13492,https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/509672/13492, [How make first letter upper-case in list of theorems?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/509738/13492)

Comment: What is the purpose of the `\patchcmd`? It does not do anything in the MWE you posted.  Perhaps you included it for other reasons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems in the code you posted, aside from what you are asking about.

1. The bit that does the `\patchcmd` does nothing in your minimal example (what it does, is to remove the theorem `title` from being shown in the `listoftheorems` *only for unnumbered theorems*. This doesn't make any sense to me so I removed it in my code below.
2. The `\makeatletter...\makeatother` pair should encompass everything that uses the `@` symbol, currently your `\declaretheoremstyle` macros do not include it, and so the code you showed does something different from its coded intent. I've moved the `\makeatother` to the correct place, and removed the declaration to remove `\thmt@space` from the basic `thmstyle`, since that space should be there and should not be removed.
3. In defining `namedtheorem`, you specified both `name` and `title`; they are synonyms and you should specify only one.

Now, on to the real problem: the use of the `\thmtformatoptarg` macro is baked firmly into how `thmtools` handle the list of theorems. Specifically, we note that:

1. The `<project>.loe` file which has all the theorem entries for the list of theorems uses `\thmtformatoptarg`. This means that any changes to `\thmtformatoptarg` will automatically apply to ALL entries, and you cannot do it selectively.
2. And someone annoyingly, the `onlynamed` key in `\listoftheorems` detects the presence of `\thmtformatoptarg` in the contents line to decide whether to   show that entry.

To work around the two problems, the following is a bit of a hack:

1. We redefine how `namedtheorem`s are written to the `loe` file, to ignore `\thmtformatoptarg` completely. This is most easily done by just completely redefining how things goes, rather than patching, so I also removed `xpatch`.
2. We assume that every instance of `namedtheorem` comes with an optional argument (if not, the theorem name would be empty....), so instead of testing for `onlynamed={namedtheorem}`, we just do `show={namedtheorem}` which should functionally be the same.

With that, the following MWE is attained:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,thmtools}


\swapnumbers

\makeatletter
\declaretheoremstyle[
  headformat=\NAME\NUMBER\NOTE,
  bodyfont=\slshape,
]{thmstyle}
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem,style=thmstyle]{theorem}
    
\declaretheoremstyle[
  postheadspace=0.5em,
  notebraces={}{},
  headformat=\NUMBER\let\thmt@space\@empty\NOTE,
  notefont=\bfseries,
  bodyfont=\slshape,
]{namedthmstyle}
\declaretheorem[
  style=namedthmstyle,
  title = \@empty,
  numberlike=theorem
]{namedtheorem}

%% Note, the following line must come AFTER the \declaretheorem...{namedtheorem}
%% as we are trying to overwrite the definition provided by thmtools
%% that occurs during the \declaretheorem process 
%% The definition below will still work if you don't \swapnumbers, but
%% it does assume that the namedtheorems are numbered. 
\@xa\def\csname ll@namedtheorem\endcsname{%
      \protect\ifthmt@listswap
        \thmt@shortoptarg~\csname thenamedtheorem\endcsname
      \protect\else
        \protect\numberline{\csname thenamedtheorem\endcsname}%
        \thmt@shortoptarg
      \protect\fi
    }%
\makeatother

\declaretheorem[name=Remark,style=thmstyle,numbered=no]{remark}


\begin{document}

\listoftheorems[ignoreall,onlynamed={theorem,remark},show={namedtheorem}]

\bigskip

\begin{namedtheorem}[Heine-Borel Theorem]
A closed and bounded subset of Euclidean $n$-space is compact.
\end{namedtheorem}

\begin{theorem}[compact subset of Hausdorff space]
A compact subset of a Hausdorff space is closed in that space.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
The square on the hypotenuse of a right triangle equals the sum of the squares on the other two sides.
\end{theorem}

\begin{remark}[Test]
    Test
\end{remark}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

---

To automate the process somewhat, if you have multiple environments, we can redefine the `\thmt@mklistcmd` to do the right thing automatically. There may be better way to do this logic, but the following should work. (Basically, instead of printing `\thmt@thmname`, we test to see if it is empty, and if true, print the optional argument instead. But this means that when it comes time to print the optional argument, we should suppress it from printing at all if it has already been used in place of the empty `\thmt@thmname`. Note: I didn't bother to make the analogous change for unnumbered theorems; hopefully you can figure out what to change yourself by comparing this with the definition in `thmtools/thm-listof.sty`.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,thmtools}

\swapnumbers
\makeatletter

\renewcommand\thmt@mklistcmd{%
  \thmtlo@newentry
  \ifthmt@isstarred
    \@xa\def\csname ll@\thmt@envname\endcsname{%
      \protect\ifthmt@listswap
      \protect\else
        \protect\numberline{\protect\let\protect\autodot\protect\@empty}%
      \protect\fi
      \thmt@thmname
      \ifx\@empty\thmt@shortoptarg\else\protect\thmtformatoptarg{\thmt@shortoptarg}\fi
    }%
  \else
    \@xa\def\csname ll@\thmt@envname\endcsname{%
      \protect\ifthmt@listswap
          \ifx\@empty\thmt@thmname\thmt@shortoptarg\else\thmt@thmname\fi~\csname the\thmt@envname\endcsname
      \protect\else
        \protect\numberline{\csname the\thmt@envname\endcsname}%
            \ifx\@empty\thmt@thmname\thmt@shortoptarg\else\thmt@thmname\fi
      \protect\fi
      \ifx\@empty\thmt@thmname\else\ifx\@empty\thmt@shortoptarg\else\protect\thmtformatoptarg{\thmt@shortoptarg}\fi\fi
    }%
  \fi
  \@xa\gdef\csname thmt@contentsline@\thmt@envname\endcsname{%
    \thmt@contentslineShow% default:show
  }%
}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  headformat=\NAME\NUMBER\NOTE,
  bodyfont=\slshape,
]{thmstyle}
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem,style=thmstyle]{theorem}
    
\declaretheoremstyle[
  postheadspace=0.5em,
  notebraces={}{},
  headformat=\NUMBER\let\thmt@space\@empty\NOTE,
  notefont=\bfseries,
  bodyfont=\slshape,
]{namedthmstyle}
\declaretheorem[
  style=namedthmstyle,
  title = \@empty,
  numberlike=theorem
]{namedtheorem}
\declaretheorem[
  style=namedthmstyle,
  title = {},
  numberlike=theorem
  ]{namedlemma}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\listoftheorems[ignoreall,onlynamed={theorem},show={namedtheorem,namedlemma}]

\bigskip

\begin{namedtheorem}[Heine-Borel Theorem]
A closed and bounded subset of Euclidean $n$-space is compact.
\end{namedtheorem}

\begin{theorem}[compact subset of Hausdorff space]
A compact subset of a Hausdorff space is closed in that space.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
The square on the hypotenuse of a right triangle equals the sum of the squares on the other two sides.
\end{theorem}

\begin{namedlemma}[Borel-Cantelli Lemma]
    Very useful in analysis
\end{namedlemma}

\end{document}
```

This provides

[image]

Comment: As an aside: the creation of the `remark` environment is because I was trying to debug your code related to the first two errors that I mentioned. It is not very relevant to the solution.

Comment: sorry about the misplaced `\makeatother` -- a result of moving code from a package (where of course `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` is not needed) to the `.tex` source.

Comment: What is the difference between `title = \@empty` and my `title = {}` ?

Comment: No difference. I was debugging something else and swapped to `\@empty` for convenience.

Comment: I also have several other "named" environments (`namedproposition`, `namedaxiom`, `namedlemma`) that need to be treated similarly to `namedtheorem`. Is there an abstraction to cover such that would avoid essentially duplicating your `ll@namedtheorem` definition for each of those (`ll@namedproposition`, etc.)?

Comment: Should your code work if it is inserted into the `\declaretheorem[...]{namedtheorem}` as a `postheadhook` option?

Comment: I was afraid you are going to ask that. I'll put in a new edit soon.

Comment: Putting it in `postheadhook` would not work. The code to write stuff to the `loe` file is implemented itself as a `postheadhook` action, and head hook action is executed FIFO. This means that any new `postheadhook` you define will be executed after the `loe` file is written. To take this approach you will have to basically make your own copy of `thm-listof.sty` and insert appropriate changes in there.

Comment: The generalized code works perfectly. Thank you!