# Problem understanding how thmtools works

Tags: thmtools

The answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168533/customizing-list-of-theorems-latex) directs me to editing `\thmt@mklistcmd` to change the appearance of the Theorem List, and it seems to be the solution, since it defines `\csname ll@\thmt@envname\endcsname` (e.g. `\ll@definame` if I say `\newtheorem{defi}{Definizione}`), which is then the responsible for that appearance. But the following MWE shows editing that command is useless:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools,amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\newtheorem{teor}{Theorem}[section]
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\thmt@mklistcmd{%
  \@xa\protected@edef\csname l@\thmt@envname\endcsname{% CHECK: why p@edef?
    \@nx\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{\@nx\thmt@listnumwidth}{\thmt@thmname}{mu}%
  }%
  \ifthmt@isstarred
    \@xa\def\csname ll@\thmt@envname\endcsname{%
      \protect\numberline{\thmt@thmname\protect\let\protect\autodot\protect:}%
      \ifx\@empty\thmt@shortoptarg\else\protect\thmtformatoptarg{\thmt@shortoptarg}\fi
    }%
  \else
    \@xa\def\csname ll@\thmt@envname\endcsname{%
      \thmt@thmname\ \csname the\thmt@envname\endcsname:\hfil%
      \ifx\@empty\thmt@shortoptarg\else\thmt@shortoptarg\fi
    }%
  \fi
  \@xa\gdef\csname thmt@contentsline@\thmt@envname\endcsname{%
    \thmt@contentslineShow% default:show
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Measures}
\begin{teor}[name=$\sigma$-subadditivity of a measure]
If $(X,\mathcal{E},\mu)$ is a measure space, then for any countable collection of measurable sets $\{A_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ we have:
\[\mu\!\left(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n\right)\leq\!\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mu(A_n).\]
\end{teor}

\listoftheorems
\end{document}
```

Compiling it as many times as you wish, you will (or at least I do) always get the same result as without the redefinition of `\thmt@mklistcmd`. However, redefining `\ll@<envname>` (e.g. `\ll@definame`) *does* work. So apparently, whether `\thmt@mklistcmd` is used or not, there must be something else defining that control sequence. So:

1. Does `\thmt@mklistcmd` have anything to do with the appearance of the theorem list, or does it not, despite the fact it appears to?
2. What is responsible for defining `\ll@<envname>` for each theorem?
3. Maybe there is something redefining `\ll@<envname>` or `\thmt@mklistcmd` at a certain point beyond my redefinition?

**Edit:**
The question is ready for closure :), since as @UlrikeFischer noted all I need to change is that the redefinition must take place *after* `\newtheorem{defi}{Definition}[section]`. Sorry for asking such a stupid question and thanks @Ulrike for your comment.

Comment: I have no idea what exactly you are trying to change but at first I would move the redefinition before `\newtheorem{teor}{Theorem}[section]`.

Comment: Whoops! That worked :). Let me edit the MWE to show the change I want.

Comment: Now if the redefinition is carried out before the `\newtheorem` I get the desired result, i.e. "Theorem 1.0.1: σ-subadditivity of a measure" in the list instead of the default "1.0.1    Theorem (σ-subadditivity of a measure)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this hasn't been closed, let me make it answered.

As Ulrike Fischer commented,

> I have no idea what exactly you are trying to change but at first I would move the redefinition before `\newtheorem{teor}{Theorem}[section]`.

And that's all you must do. Evidently defining the theorem before redefining `mklistcmd` makes the theorem have the old `mklistcmd` whereas defining it afterwards makes it have the desired new `mklistcmd`.