# alphabetical order in listoftheorems

Tags: sorting, thmtools

I use the package `thmtools` to generate a List of my Definitions at the end of the Document. This works fine, but the list is orderd by chapter and not orderd by the name of the definition.

Here's some code:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[
%spaceabove=6pt, spacebelow=6pt,
headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
notefont=\normalfont\bfseries, notebraces={(}{)},
bodyfont=\normalfont,
postheadspace=1em,
headpunct={:},
]{mystyle}
\declaretheorem[numberwithin=section,style=mystyle]{definition}
\renewcommand{\listtheoremname}{Definitionsverzeichnis}

\begin{document}
    \begin{definition}[Foobar]
        Lorem ipsum...
    \end{definition}

    \begin{definition}[Abar]
        Lorem ipsum...
    \end{definition}
\end{document}
```

If I compile this, I got the following List of Theorems:

```
 1 Definition (Foobar)...............1
 2 Definition (Abar).................1
```

But I want this:

```
 2 Definition (Abar).................1
 1 Definition (Foobar)...............1
```

Better this:

```
 Abar.................1
 Foobar...............1
```

Comment: Nothing in the `thmtools` induces to think that the list can be sorted. You probably want something based on the `glossaries` package.

Comment: I don't think, that `glossaries` is what I want. But I saw this post (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16498/14290) and it makes the 'Definition' Text disappear. That helps a bit.

Comment: It sounds like you want an index of definitions.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472/how-can-i-have-two-or-more-distinct-indexes