# Changing Figure label to Map or some other label

Tags: captions

I am writing a report that has graphics, photos and maps. If I use the figure environment everything is labeled as a figure in the caption. However, what I would like to do is where I have a map to have the map labeled appropriately e.g. Map 1: caption text; Map 2: caption text etc and to be able to refer to it in the text Map \ref{map01}. Same as for Photographs.

I have looked at some of the FAQs but does not seem to have what I want.  Is it possible.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `\renewcommand{figurename}{Map}` should do, but you have to change it back later on to `\renewcommand{figurename}{Figure}`. Usage of the `caption` package could help

Answer (score 9):

If you use the `tocbasic` package from the KOMA-Script bundle you can also print a list of photos and a list of maps.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\DeclareNewTOC[%
  type=photo,
  float,
  name=Photo,
  listname={List of Photos},
  ]{pho}
\DeclareNewTOC[%
  type=map,
  float,
  name=Map,
  listname={List of Maps},
  ]{map}
\makeatletter
% entries to the lists should have the same layout like entries to the list of figures
  \renewcommand\l@photo{\l@figure}
  \renewcommand\l@map{\l@figure}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\listofphotos
\listofmaps

\begin{figure}[ht] \centering\fbox{Figure}\caption{A figure} \end{figure}
\begin{photo}[ht] \centering\fbox{Photo}\caption{A photo} \end{photo}
\begin{map}[ht] \centering\fbox{Map}\caption{A map} \end{map}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There is also a `nonfloat` option for `\DeclareNewTOC`. It defines the (additional) nonfloating environment `<name>-` (for example `photo-`).

Answer (score 7):

Define yourself new floats that match the type you're using:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}% http://ctan.org/pkg/float
\newfloat{photo}{htbp}{pho}\floatname{photo}{Photo}
\newfloat{map}{htbp}{map}\floatname{map}{Map}
\setcounter{topnumber}{3}% Just for this example
\begin{document}
Text
\begin{figure}[t] \caption{A figure} \end{figure}
\begin{photo}[t] \caption{A photo} \end{photo}
\begin{map}[t] \caption{A map} \end{map}
\end{document}
```

The [`float` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/float) provides

```
\newfloat{<type>}{<placement>}{<ext>}[<within>]
```

Answer (score 4):

My solution uses the `caption` package and its `\captionsetup` facility, however, this way it is necessary to do this in every `figure` environment where the name should be changed.

This will also not provide different counters or separate `lists of maps` etc.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{caption}%
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}%


\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\chapter{First}


\begin{figure}
\captionsetup{name=Map}%
\centering
\includegraphics{somefig}%
\caption{Some Text}%
\end{figure}



\begin{figure}
\captionsetup{name=Photo}%
\centering
\includegraphics{somefig}%
\caption{This photograph shows ...}%
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]

**The figure "2" below the 'Map' is the pagenumber ;-)**