# Referring to figure with different label

Tags: floats, hyperref, cross-referencing, autoref

I am using the following code from [Changing Figure label to Map or some other label](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191346/changing-figure-label-to-map-or-some-other-label) to have Map as a label.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}% http://ctan.org/pkg/float
\newfloat{map}{htbp}{map}\floatname{map}{Map}
\setcounter{topnumber}{1}% Just for this example

\begin{document}

\begin{map}[t] \caption{A map \label{map:europe}} \end{map}

\end{document}
```

When I then use `autoref` to refer to it, only the number (for example, "3") appears, and not "Map 3". Is there a way to make "Map 3" appear? I can type "Map" before `autoref`, but the link to the referred map is just the number, which is small and difficult to click on. With tables and figures I get "Table 3" and "Figure 3" automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the appropriate `\<float>autorefname` accompaniment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{float}
\newfloat{map}{htbp}{map}
\floatname{map}{Map}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\mapautorefname}{Map}

\begin{document}

See \autoref{map:europe}.

\begin{map}
  \caption{A map \label{map:europe}}
\end{map}

\end{document}
```