# Create list of examples

Tags: lists, amsthm, ntheorem, examples

I used the amsthm-package to define definitions, theorems and lemmas. Besides, I defined examples as follows:

```
\newtheoremstyle{examplestyle}
{2pt}
{2pt}
{}
{}
{\bfseries}
{:}
{3pt}
{}
\theoremstyle{examplestyle}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[chapter]
```

Now I would like to make a list of examples (similar to \listoffigures). I tried to use the ntheorem-package, but that is not compatible with amsthm. Does anyone know if it is possible to create a list of examples without having to change the things I defined so far and how to do so?

Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: the package `thmtools` (compatible with `amsthm`) provides the desired facility.  see [Generating lists of custom environment.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16494/579)

Comment: I have voted for close as duplicate. See comment thanks comment of OP and the duplicate comment of baraba beeton