# list of counted objects

Tags: table-of-contents

I have been using the following commands in my preamble.

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{exmp}{Example}[section]

\newcounter{Examplecounter}
\newenvironment{MathematicalBackground}{%
  \begin{quote}%
    \refstepcounter{Examplecounter}%
    \textbf{Mathematical Background \arabic{Examplecounter}}%
    \quad
}{%
  \end{quote}%
}
```

Then in the text I am using the following.

```
\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=brown!20]
  \begin{MathematicalBackground}
    ...
  \end{MathematicalBackground}
\end{mdframed}
```

I also have a different type of region in the text defined by,

```
\begin{exmp}
  \begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=blue!20]
    ...
  \end{mdframed}
\end{exmp}
```

With figures and tables we can create lists at the front of the document by using `\listof...` commands. How can I get a list of these two environments at the front of the document? I am aware of this [TEX post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16494/generating-lists-of-custom-environment) but still can not define my lists.

Many thanks for your help!

**Edit**

From the link I entered

```
\usepackage{thmtools}
\renewcommand{\listoftheoremname}{MathematicalBackground}
```

Then entered the following at the start of the text.

```
\listoftheorems[ignoreall,show={MathematicalBackground}]
```

I also tried swapping MathematicalBackground for expm. All wouldn't parse, so I am definitely doing something very wrong here.

Comment: Although a duplicate question I still can not manage to generate a list of both environments from the information in the linked question.

Comment: In that case it would greatly help us if you showed what you tried and explained what in the link did not work as expected. A full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) would then greatly improve our chances of understanding your problem.