# Manual label to figure

Tags: cross-referencing

I would like to know if it is possible to manually decide how to reference a figure. I want to include a map as a figure environment, but with the reference "Map 1: ..." instead of "Figure 1: ...". How can this be done?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16495/15036 for some packages that do this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**First Solution *(Only Maps in the Document)***

Here, I assume that all your *figures* will be maps. So, there will not be anything called a Figure per se.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\figurename}{Map}

\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{List of Maps}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\clearpage

\lipsum[1-4]

\begin{figure}[!tb]
  \centering
  Here, my map will be included
  \caption{Here is my map.}
  \label{fig:map1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

[image] [image]

---

**Second Solution *(Both Maps and Figures in the Document)***

In this solution, I assume that you are likely to have *both* figures and maps and would like to use different types of floats for each.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=map,name=Map]{map}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\listofmaps

\clearpage

\lipsum[1-4]

\begin{map}[!tb]
  \centering
  Here, my MAP will be included
  \caption{Here is my map.}
  \label{fig:map1}
\end{map}


\begin{figure}[!tb]
  \centering
  Here, my FIGURE will be included
  \caption{Here is my figure.}
  \label{fig:fig1}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

---

[image]
[image]